# How can I display the content of the "tags" object using angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I display the content of the "tags" object using angular?

I tried to do it using 

{{gallery.tags.tag}}

 but it does not work

```js
import {IPhoto} from "./iphoto";

export interface IGallery {
  galleryId: string;
  title: string;
  dateCreated: string;
  thumbUrl: string;
  description: string;
  tags?: any;
  photos: IPhoto[];

}
```

```js
export const Galleries = [{
    'galleryId': '1',
    'title': 'Chiny',
    'dateCreated': '2017-11-15T00:00:00+00:00',
    'thumbUrl': './assets/img/gallery/D1.jpg',
    'description': 'Wakacje w Chinach',
    'tags': [{
        'tag': 'Indonezja',
    }, {
        'tag': 'Woda'
    }],
```

galerry.component.html

```js
<h2>Galeria: {{gallery.title}}
    <p><small>{{gallery.dateCreated | polishDate | uppercase}}</small></p>
    <br><small>galleryId: {{gallery.galleryId}}</small>
    <p>des: {{gallery.description}}</p>
    <img src="{{gallery.thumbUrl}}">
```

Comment: go to angular docs and look up ngFor

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: I've tried a few modifications 
   <li *ngFor="let tag of Galleries">
      <p> {{gallery.tags.tag}}</p>
    </li>

 but it does not work. Can you tell me something?

Answer (score 1):

You need `*ngFor`

```html
<div *ngFor="let gallery of galleries">
    <p><small>{{gallery.dateCreated | polishDate | uppercase}}</small></p>
    <br><small>galleryId: {{gallery.galleryId}}</small>
    <p>des: {{gallery.description}}</p>
    <img src="{{gallery.thumbUrl}}">
    <div>
        <span *ngFor="let tag of gallery.tags">
            {{tag.tag}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```